# find method not working in lwc with lightning-radio object array

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-radiogroup, find

I am having problem with find method on an array of objects (options) being used for lighting-radio-group. My goal is to get the label of the option selected. Can you please let me know what I am doing wrong? The find method on the normal array of objects (objArr) works fine.

testCmp.js

```
import { LightningElement, track} from 'lwc';

export default class testCmp extends LightningElement {
    objArr = [
        {
        label: 'mno',
        value: 'pqr'
    },
    {
        label: 'stu',
        value: 'vwx'
    }
    ];

    options = [
        {
        label: 'mno',
        value: 'pqr'
    },
    {
        label: 'stu',
        value: 'vwx'
    }
    ];
    
    selectedObj1;

    selectedObj2;

    @track selectedValue;


    handleChange(event){
        
        //find on normal object array
        this.selectedObj1 = this.objArr.find(function(elem) {
            return elem.value === 'pqr'; 
        });
        console.log(this.selectedObj1); // {label: 'mno', value: 'pqr'}
        console.log(this.selectedObj1.label); //mno

        //find on options which is also ideally an object
        this.selectedValue = event.detail.value; 
        console.log(this.selectedValue);  // up to here, it is working fine.
        this.selectedObj2 = this.options.find(function(elem) {  // this line gives error
            return elem.value === this.selectedValue; 
        });
        console.log(this.selectedObj2);
        console.log(this.selectedObj2.label);

    }
        
}
```

testCmp.html

```
 <template>
        <lightning-card>
            <div class="slds-p-medium_around">
                <lightning-radio-group name="test" label="test" options={options} value={value} type="radio"
                    onchange={handleChange}>
                </lightning-radio-group>
            </div>
        </lightning-card>
    </template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're in a class, the code runs in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode):

> All parts of ECMAScript classes are strict mode code, including both class declarations and class expressions — and so also including all parts of class bodies.

```js
this.selectedObj2 = this.options.find(function(elem) {
    return elem.value === this.selectedValue; 
});
```

Here you have defined an anonymous function. In strict mode the value of `this` is not set when entering an execution context, [it remains as undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#function_context). That's why `this.selectedValue` throws an error.

In order to retains the `this` value of the enclosing lexical context you have two options: you could either use [`bind(this)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which set the value of function's `this` to the provided value, or use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), that inherits `this`.

**Bind**:

```js
this.selectedObj2 = this.options.find(function(elem) {
    return elem.value === this.selectedValue; 
}.bind(this)); // bind the value of this
```

**Arrow function**:

```js
this.selectedObj2 = this.options.find((elem) => {
    return elem.value === this.selectedValue; 
});
```

The latter is usually the preferred method.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Good to know about the strict mode. However, I still get the error. I tried both using .bind(this) and arrow function.

Comment: Also, I think the 'return' will not be there in the arrow function:

this.selectedObj2 = this.options.find((elem) => {
    elem.value === this.selectedValue; 
});

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I believe I was doing something wrong or I checked too soon. It is working now. Also, your arrow function is correct. Thanks again!